# VSCode Vim: map to function key

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscodevim

I'm trying out VSCode Vim and I'm having trouble remapping `<leader>d` to a `Go To Definition` action.

I've found that `F12` is a `Go To Definition` shortcut in VSCode - now I'd like to set up a mapping from `<leader>d` to `F12` but I can't figure it out.

I've tried the following without luck:

```
    "vim.normalModeKeyBindings": [
        {
            "before": ["leader", "d"],
            "after": ["<F12>"]
        }
    ]
```

I can see VSCode Vim capturing the `leader` command when in normal mode on one of my golang files but then when I hit `d` nothing happens. However, if I manually invoke `F12` then I can see VSCode navigate to the definition of the symbol under the cursor.

What's the correct way to set up this mapping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found another way to achieve this:

```
        {
            "before": ["leader", "d"],
            "commands": [
                "editor.action.revealDefinition"
            ]
        },
```